# How to display the Image property in the Views of ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, qr-code

I want to convert my code number of my card  to QR image, so I added one reference to my project. Then I created one method in my Helper Class :

```
public static Image GenerateQRCode(String code)
{
  QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
  QrCode qrCode = new QrCode();
  qrEncoder.TryEncode(code, out qrCode);
  Renderer renderer = new Renderer(5, Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

And then I call this function in my view :

```
  <%
     System.Drawing.Image image = ICEWeb.HelperClasses.HelperClass.GenerateQRCode("test");
  %>
```

But it display only `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, Does anyone knwo how to display the System.Drawing.Image that return from my function `GenerateQRCode()` ?

Thna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it MVCishly: by writing a custom action result. The `GenerateQRCode` method that you currently have is something that you could leave behind in the legacy application where it was taken from.

```
public class QRCodeResult : ActionResult
{
    public QRCodeResult(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }

    public string Code { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "image/png";

        QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
        QrCode qrCode = new QrCode();
        qrEncoder.TryEncode(Code, out qrCode);
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer(5, Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);
        renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

and then a controller action:

```
public ActionResult QRCode(string code)
{
    return new QRCodeResult(code);
}
```

and finally in some view where you want to display the QR code use an `<img>` tag pointing to the controller action you wrote:

```
<img src="<%: Url.Action("QRCode", new { code = "test" }) %>" alt="" />
```